# Why don't some template tags work when querying information on single.php?

Tags: functions, loop, facebook, template-tags

I'm trying to fetch content about the current post into the header.php of my theme (to dynamically insert Facebook OpenGraph Metadata).

Since I'm on a single post page, shouldn't it be able to run functions like `the_content()` or `wp_get_attachment_thumb_url()`?

```
<?php if (is_single()) { 
          <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo get_the_title()." - Advocate Daily" ?>" />
          <meta property="og:description" content="<?php string_limit_words(the_content(), 15);" ?> />
          <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

In the above example, the first tag works, but the content of the other two isn't outputted.

Does this mean certain template tags needs to be in the

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

loop? Do I need to declare this loop again in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this snippet [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-facebook-open-graph-tags-to-wordpress) to accomplish your task. If you add it to your `functions.php` file, the Open Graph tags will be populated automatically as part of the `wp_head` action.

Answer (score 2):

First line of the codex for [get_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content):

> Displays the contents of the current post. **This template tag must be
>   within The_Loop.**

Also, this line:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php string_limit_words(the_content(), 15);" ?> />
```

would need to `get_the_content()`, as `the_content()` will output, and you need to return.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_content(), 15);" ?> />
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in Codex too, and I originally tried it with get_the_content() and the_content(), but it doesn't work.
Neither does wp_get_attachment_thumb_url().